# why woff font doesn't work properly in my code

Tags: html, css

I used this font face and it works fine:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSansWebLight;
    src: url(fonts/IRANSansWeb_Light.ttf) format("truetype")
}
```

But when I try to use the same font which is converted to woff it doesn't work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSansWebLight;
    src: url(fonts/iransansweb_light-webfont.woff) format("woff");
}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know about your folder structure, I would suggest you to change the URL of the font to:

```
url(../fonts/iransansweb_light-webfont.woff)
```

If that doesn't fix your problem, you should try to use Google Font Helper. Search for your desired font and follow the instructions. Here's a [link](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts) to it.